# Collision detection in Pygame between Player and sprite group mudballGroup

Tags: python, pygame

I am following along with a tutorial on how to detect collisions between the class Player and a sprite group MudballGroup. When setting up the collision in the statement pg.sprite.spritecollide(Player, mudballGroup, False) I get the error type object 'Player' has no attribute 'rect'. I have code from my Player sprite here that shows rect to be defined in the following statement: self.rect = self.image.get_rect(). I don't know why I am getting this error. Please if someone could help.

```
class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):
     def __init__(self, game):
       pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
       self.game = game
       self.walking = False
       self.jumping = False
       self.current_frame = 0
       self.last_update = 0
       self.load_images()
       self.image = self.girl_standing[0]
       #Isn't this my rect attribute for Player?
       self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
       self.rect.center = (WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2)
       self.pos = vec(WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2)
       self.vel = vec(0, 0)
       self.acc = vec(0, 0)
       self.screen = pg.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
       self.clock = pg.time.Clock()

 def shoot(self):

          mudball = MUDBALL(self.rect.centerx, self.rect.centery)
          print("SHOOT function")
          self.game.all_sprites.add(mudball)

          mudballGroup = pg.sprite.Group()
          mudballGroup.add(mudball)

 # Me attempting collision

        hits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(self.player, mudballGroup, False)
        if hits:
            print("HITS!!!!!!!!", hits)


def hailing(self):
        jets = JETS()
        print("FLYOVER")
        self.game.all_sprites.add(jets)
        jetsGroup = pg.sprite.Group()

        jetsGroup.add(jets)

 class MUDBALL(pg.sprite.Sprite):
      def __init__(self, x, y):
          pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
          self.image = pg.image.load("SLIMEballGREEN.png")
          # self.mudballGroup = pg.sprite.Group()
          self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
          self.rect.bottom = y
          self.rect.centerx = x
          self.speedx = -30


  def update(self):
          self.rect.x += self.speedx
          #kill if moves off screen
          if self.rect.centerx < 0:
            self.kill()

 class JETS(pg.sprite.Sprite):
     def __init__(self):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pg.image.load("JETSscaled.png")
        #self.jetsGroup = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = 1366
        self.rect.y = 0
        self.speedx = -70

 def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.speedx
        #kill if moves off screen
        if self.rect.x + 848 < 0:
            self.kill()
```

Comment: ``Player`` is a class. You need to make an instance of it to actually use it in your. program. See https://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex40.html

Comment: I'd rather recommend Program Arcade Games [chapters about classes and sprites](http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?chapter=introduction_to_classes&lang=de#section_12) (12 and 13).

Comment: Please keep in mind that you should post [complete but minimal examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) here. We want code that we can copy, paste and run.

Comment: Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the `Player` class for the collision detection, but you have to use an instance of this class instead.

```
# Player is the class, but spritecollide needs an instance.
hits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(Player, mudballGroup, False)
```

To create an instance of the `Player` class, just write:

```
# Don't forget to pass the game instance to the `Player`s __init__ method.
player = Player(game)
```

It also looks odd to me that you define the `mudballGroup` inside of the `shoot` method. That means the group will only contain one mudball, but then you could also just check if the rects of the player and mudball collide: `player.rect.colliderect(mudball.rect)` instead of `spritecollide`. However, if you want multiple mudballs you need to store the `mudballGroup` as an attribute of the other class, in the `__init__` method write:

```
self.mudballGroup = pg.sprite.Group()
```

**Edit**: Okay, you already have a `self.player` instance in your game instance. I recommend to define the `mudballGroup` in the `Game` class as well and then just pass it and the `all_sprites` group to the player's `shoot` method to add a mudball. The collision detection can be done inside the game's `update` method.

```
class Game:

    def new(self):
        # Other code omitted ...
        self.mudballGroup = pg.sprite.Group()

    def update(self):
        # Check if the player is shooting.
        if self.player.shooting:  # You have to add a `shooting` attribute to player.
            # `shoot` just adds a mudball to these groups.
            self.player.shoot(self.all_sprites, self.mudballGroup)
        # Then detect collisions.
        hits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(self.player, self.mudballGroup, False)
        if hits:
            print("HITS!!!!!!!!", hits)


class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    # Pass the sprite groups of the game to the shoot method.
    def shoot(self, all_sprites, mudballGroup):
        mudball = MUDBALL(self.player.centerx, self.player.centery)
        # Add sprite to the passed groups.
        all_sprites.add(mudball)
        mudballGroup.add(mudball)
```

**Edit 2**: Here's the other variant. Pass the two needed sprite groups to the player when you create the instance (you don't have to pass the complete game instance), then set them as attributes of the player.

```
class Game:

    def new(self):
        # Other code omitted ...
        self.all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.mudballGroup = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.player = Player(self.all_sprites, self.mudballGroup)

    def update(self):
        # Check if the player is shooting.
        if self.player.shooting:
            # `shoot` adds a mudball to self.all_sprites & self.mudballGroup.
            self.player.shoot()
        # Then detect collisions.
        hits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(self.player, self.mudballGroup, False)
        if hits:
            print("HITS!!!!!!!!", hits)


class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, all_sprites, mudballGroup):
        # Other code omitted ...
        # These two attributes are references to the groups
        # that were defined in the Game class.
        self.all_sprites = all_sprites
        self.mudballGroup = mudballGroup

    def shoot(self):
        mudball = MUDBALL(self.player.centerx, self.player.centery)
        # Add sprite to the passed groups.
        self.all_sprites.add(mudball)
        self.mudballGroup.add(mudball)
```

**Edit 3**: Okay, forget the `shooting` attribute (it would only be needed for the player instance to check if the user is shooting). You also don't need to call trump's `shoot` method in the Game class, since you already call it in his `update` method. So here's the updated code:

```
class Game(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def new(self):
        # Other code omitted ...
        self.all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.mudballGroup = pg.sprite.Group()
        # Pass the groups to trump during the instantiation.
        # You don't have to pass the complete game instance (self).
        self.trump = TRUMP(self.all_sprites, self.mudballGroup)
        self.all_sprites.add(self.trump)

    def update(self):
        hits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(self.player, self.mudballGroup, False)
        for collided_sprite in hits:
            print("HIT", collided_sprite)


class TRUMP(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, all_sprites, mudballGroup):
        # Now set the passed groups as attributes of the trump instance.
        # These attributes are references to the same sprite groups as
        # in the Game class.
        self.all_sprites = all_sprites
        self.mudballGroup = mudballGroup

    def shoot(self):
        print("SHOOT function")
        mudball = MUDBALL(self.rect.centerx, self.rect.centery)
        # Add the mudball to the groups.
        self.all_sprites.add(mudball)
        self.mudballGroup.add(mudball)
```

Comment: Excuse me I am new to this. I would prefer to use spritecollide for simplicity. How do I code for an instance of player? Is it self.Player? If I don't make the mudball group there where should it go? thanks very much for the help.

Comment: I've edited the answer to show you how you can create a player instance/object. Also, the mudballGroup should probably be an attribute of the other class, then you can keep using the `spritecollide` function.

Comment: I actually guess you already have a player instance somewhere, otherwise your game wouldn't work at all. So the other class either needs a reference to this `player` instance or you need to pass it as an argument to the `shoot` method. If I could see the complete code I could probably give you more advice, but Stack Overflow isn't the correct site for code review. When your code works correctly, you can post it on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ to get some tips.

Comment: I put in that line into the code (player = Player(game)) and it does not work. I know you want me to figure this out myself but I still have no idea. As well when I put the group declaration in the __init__ of the class it is no longer referenced in the method shoot so mudballGroup is then undefined. Thanks for all the help but I am still confused.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141289/discussion-between-skrx-and-matt-macy).